# Show/hide primeng datatable rows dynamically

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a primeng datatable which shows thousand rows. The table looks something like below.

```
| period | value |
------------------
| A      | 12    |
| A      | 13    |
| B      | 12    |
| C      | 13    |
| D      | 12    |
| D      | 13    |
```

the template for this table is below.

```
<p-table [columns]="columns" [value]="tableData">
```

In component.ts , I am having tableData defined like below.

tableData =`[{'period':'A','value':12},{'period':'A','value':12},....]`

All of this is working great. Now a list is added next to the table which has period listed one by one like below.

```
A
B
C
D
```

Whenever anyone clicks on any of these period values, I want only the rows in the table remain visible which have this period as their column value. Rest all rows should disappear.

For a UIChart , its easy to do via hidden property on `UIChart.data.dataset`

I am not sure how to approach this. Any help ?

Comment: add a click row event, and use a copy of the tableData on the template.
When the row is clicked, just filter the copied table data

Comment: Based on @CaioOliveira 's comment here is a demo, maybe it can help you  (https://stackblitz.com/edit/t6bb2c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-dynamic-demo.ts)[stackblitz-demo]